# Why the function is not returning the string?

Tags: c++, string, algorithm, recursion, reverse

```
#include<iostream>
#include<string.h>
using namespace std;

string revString(string s,string copy,int i,int j)
{   
    if(i==s.length())
        return copy;//if 'i' reaches to the length of the string it returns the copied value
    else{
        copy[i]=s[j];//copying the string s into copy
        return revString(s,copy,++i,--j);// calling recursively 
    }
}

int main()
{
    string s,copy;
    cout<<"Enter a string without entering spaces\n";   
    cin>>s;
    int i=0,j=s.length()-1;
    cout<<revString(s,copy,i,j);//function for reversing the string
    return 0;
}
```

here i am trying to copy the string 's' into the  string 'copy' by using recursion but the function isn't returning anything.

Comment: Print `copy` at each iteration, you should be able to figure out what is going on.

Comment: Strings do not expand when you assign to non-existent elements of them. Instead, the behaviour is undefined.

Comment: `std::string rev{s.rbegin(), s.rend()};`?

Comment: `revString(s,s,i,j);` should fix issue reported by molbdnilo.

Comment: Add `if (copy.length() == 0) copy.resize(s.length());`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because you have not allocated memory to your `copy` variable, but trying to assign values to it. I would suggest you to read more about memory allocation in C++ `string` class.

With minimum alterations to your code, you can make it work by adding the following snippet just before calling your `revString()` function:

```
copy.resize(s.size());
```

Comment: Well, I was expecting this answer. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

your approch was good but imagine you have 100 chars then it will iterate 100 times. instead what you can do reverse first half with second half of string and you don't even have to pass too many arguments.

this is my approch

```cpp
#include<iostream>
#include<string.h>
using namespace std;

string revString(string s, int i = 0)
{
    if((int)(s.length()  / 2) == i)
        return s;
    else{
        char t;
        t = s[i];
        s[i] = s[s.length() - 1 - i];
        s[s.length() - 1 - i]=t;
        return revString(s, ++i);// calling recursively 
    }
}

int main()
{
    string s;
    cout<<"Enter a string without entering spaces\n";   
    cin>>s;;
    cout<<revString(s);//function for reversing the string
    return 0;
}
```